# Freelancing intermediary for business invoice

Tags: legal, taxes, invoices, accounting

I'm a part time freelancer but don't yet own a business as the work is too sporadic and accounting expenses and paperwork are too much of an overhead for now.

I've provided services for someone in Norway and they requested an organisation number on the invoice.

What are my options, are there any intermediaries that can help? For example will selling the services as a downloadable (on ebay or some other service) suffice for their accounting? Or should we creeate accounts on oDesk.com or elance.com and pay their comission ?

Business wise he knows my situation so not doing this in a professional matter won't be a problem, but of course I wouldn't mind learning of an other way.

---

## Update 1

Legally in my country I don't need anything other than a end-of-the-year declaration to state my income and that's it, so don't need a company for that, or any paperwork, I'm just interested in getting the other part sorted.

Comment: Why don't you tell them that you do not have the ID? Maybe they can put n/a. My clients often ask me for the ID as they need to prove expense in their own country. If you use some freelancing website, then charges will be more than 4% that paypal charges.

Comment: unfortunately they said the accountant needs an org nr. on the invoice, so "N/A" in not an option. @PeterMV what freelancing websites do you know, that have the lowest commission, or are best suited for this ?

Comment: ok  I've seen your answer :) 
http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/freelance-site-with-lowest-commission-fees

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you should get this number by filling a form at the government business registration center for your self-employed work. They will give you the business number the buyer requires.

Technically, they don't need that number but some clients may require it. It won't help to go through Elance or any other freelancer website.